# Finding features of Xcode3 in Xcode5+

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5, xcode6, xcode3.2

My first day with Mac/Apple and <s>Xcode5.2</s> (Updated: as well as 6.0.1), and I am watching a video lesson on Xcode3.2.1.

The movie shows and narrates about the following tabs in Xcode3.2.1 editor:

- On the upper left:

  - History tab ("`PlayFile.m:2`" on the screenshot below)
  - Functions List tab ("`<No selected symbol>`" on screenshot below)
- On the upper right:

  - Bookmarks List tab
  - Breakpoints List tab
  - Class navigation tab
  - List of Included Files Tab
  - Counterparts tab (bouncing between `.m` and `.h` files)
  - Lock File tab (in the upper right corner)
  - Split the editor view

Tooltip on the "Split the editor view" tab in XCode3:

[image: Popupping on the "Split the editor view" tab in XCode3.2.1]

The result of splitting the editor window in Xcode3.2.1. upon pressing the last button (on the right, below lock tab) in XCode3:

[image: The result of splitting the editor window in Xcode3.2.1. upon pressing the last tab (on the right, below lock tab) in XCode3.2.1]

What I see in Xcode5.1.1 is:

[image: XCode5.1.1 editor windows]

Updated: the same as in **Xcode 6.0.1**:

[image: Xcode 6.0.1]

My questions:

- How can I split the editor window in Xcode5/Xcode6?
- Where is history, bookmarks, counterparts, etc. in <s>Xcode5</s> Xcode6?
- Can I get the Xcode3 "look and feel" in <s>Xcode5</s> Xcode6?

Comment: `My first day with Mac/Apple and Xcode5.2..` time to update to 6.0.1 ;-)

Comment: @HAS, thanks, I missed it. It is an update from 18 September 2014, updating now

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do a split is right-click in the file you're editing and choose "open in assistant editor".

Most of the other things you're asking about are either the tabs just above where the word "Strings" appears near the top left of your window or menu items from the drop down menu just above the column where you set breakpoints (strange icon with 8 small vertical rectangles).

But, really, you'd be better off looking at instructions for the version you're going to use rather than trying to figure out and remember translations.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for "assistant editor", that's quite nonintuitive and impossible to guess.... Concerning your phrase "just above where the word Strings" -  but the word "Strings" appears all over the Xcode - left, right, top, bottom. How can I open the list of bookmarks, counterparts, history?

Comment: There was a "top left" phrase in there.  :)  Just below the dark triangle that does a "build & run", there's a row of icons.  Each of them changes the display in the left-most column.  Click some of those.

Comment: I understood your  "top left" phrase but specifically asked about list of bookmarks, counterparts, history which Iэму failed to find there